# German-style quotation marks in LuaLaTeX using polyglossia

Tags: luatex, punctuation, german

Could someone post a complete minimal input file for LuaLaTeX to output

> "Hallo"

also to get around ,,Hallo´´

In LaTeX I would have written

```
``Hallo´´


%% Minimal Inputfile for LuaLaTeX
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new, babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\enquote{Hallo--mit enquote--this is working}

But: how to produce the euivalent Text, based on babelshorthands?

“`Hallo”’  --- is not working

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hallo. Ich verstehe nicht richtig was Du machen willst. Willst Du "Hallo" drucken oder ,,Hallo´´ ?

Comment: Better: `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} \usepackage{csquotes}` & `Ich schreibe ``Hallo'' so: \enquote{Hallo}.`

Answer (score 2):

For babel-style shortcuts, don't use "smart" quotes: using "dumb" double quotes is the way to go.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new, babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\enquote{Hallo} --- with \texttt{\string\enquote}, this works

"`Hallo"'  --- with \verb+"`+ and \verb+"'+, this works too
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The conversion from ``` ``Hello'' ``` to `„Hello“` via a feature file.

Disadvantages:

- Copy&paste will catch the first form.
- LuaTeX only.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{germanquotes.fea}
# germanquotes.fea
languagesystem DFLT dflt ;
languagesystem latn dflt ;

feature liga {
  sub \grave \grave by \quotedblbase;
  sub \quotesingle \quotesingle by \quotedblleft;
} liga;
\end{filecontents*}

\setmainfont[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  FeatureFile={germanquotes.fea},
]{Latin Modern Roman}

\begin{document}
  ``Hello'' -- fi fl

  \textit{``Hello'' -- fi fl}

  \textbf{``Hello'' -- fi fl}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

<sub>Disclaimer: My first experiment with a feature file.</sub>